# Read value passed by parent component

Tags: angular

I have a child textbox component as `"app-ec-textbox"`

HTML for app-ec-textbox

```
<input type="text" #txtBox [ngModel]="value" (focus)="validate(value)">
```

in ts file for  app-ec-textbox, I have function *validate()* defined as below

```
@Input() value: string = "";

validate(val: string) {
        console.log(val)
      }
```

i use above child textbox component in parent component like below

```
      <app-ec-textbox [value]="abc"></app-ec-textbox>
```

**The problem is I don't get value "abc" logged in console when I click and set focus on child textbox component "app-ec-textbox". I want value "abc" to be captured in focus event. How to achieve this?**

Comment: it seems you need ngModel set like banana-in-the-box: `[(ngModel)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change it to a focus event **(focus)="validate($event)"**

```
<input type="text" #txtBox [(ngModel)]="value" (focus)="validate($event)">


validate(event: any) {
  console.log(event.target.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass values to properties declared in `[]` you're passing directly code, just to be clear, i'll make an example:
This:

```html
<app-ec-textbox [value]="abc"></app-ec-textbox>
```

It's equal to this:

```html
<app-ec-textbox value="{{ abc }}"></app-ec-textbox>
```

In this way you're evaluating some code before and then your passing the returned value to the prop.

You haven't posted anything related to some prop called `abc` so what's appening is that angular tries to find a variable called `abc` and pass its value to the child prop.

If you want to pass just a string of course yo ucan do that by:

```html
<app-ec-textbox [value]="'abc'"></app-ec-textbox> <!-- note the ' -->
```

But you can just:

```html
<app-ec-textbox value="abc"></app-ec-textbox>
```

Now that you're passing the right values to the child you have to bind the property with the ng model, to do that you can use the [two-way binding](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding) to the value:

```html
<input type="text" #txtBox [(ngModel)]="value" (focus)="validate(value)">
```

Comment: "abc" is just an example. it will be actually a property name in parent TS file.